# How to make an HTML table with a single cell mobile responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a single cell that has a load of paragraph elements in that are underscores (it is basically meant to look like a form hence the underscores).

The structure of the table can't be changed and has to be pure html/css.

This table looks fine on desktop but not on a mobile view and I'm not sure how to fix it so that the underscores fit into the mobile view because currently when I go to mobile view i have to scroll to see this table and I don' want that.

```css
.td {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
}

.p {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3><strong>Title</strong></h3>
        <p>name</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>_____________________________________</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Details</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>
          ___________________________________________________________________________
        </p>
        <p></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a `border` instead of adding underscores ?

Comment: @Cédric this is the way its been set up so I have to go with this layout unfortunately

Comment: That's pretty crappy HTML code to be honest. I think the underscores make the table cell break out of the screen. What if you add a `overflow: hidden` to the table-cell?

Comment: "this is the way its been set up", do you not have access/permission to change that? If you are able to change enough to make it responsive you should really be able to improve what's there.

Comment: Semantic markup is important. Push back if you can.

Comment: Your question implies that you need a CSS-only solution. Is that true? Can the markup be changed in any way? Can JavaScript be used? Please revise to clarify the parameters here.

Comment: Why are you using a table for layout instead of CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@media` query with a specific width. try implementing the same code and it should work just fine.

Comment: This answer isn't specific enough. Please see [answer].

Comment: @isherwood i've edited the question to be more specific let me know if its okay

Comment: @MinaN25 note that isherwood's comment was about an answer, but don't hesitate to specify in the question that you don't want to change the html structure as you said in comment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.td {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.p {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.box-one {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.box-two {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3><strong>Title</strong></h3>
        <p>name</p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="box-one">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio illum incidunt natus beatae aut itaque harum dolorum quas, in exercitationem? Voluptate ipsum quae consequuntur expedita natus numquam facilis, rem libero illum placeat, tenetur enim
          reiciendis est odit distinctio molestiae minus omnis aliquid dignissimos soluta repellendus non eius? In, quaerat ut.</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Details</p>
        <p></p>
        <p class="box-two">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, impedit magnam. Reprehenderit, eius natus! Suscipit reprehenderit rem repellendus quos obcaecati excepturi eligendi labore dolore quidem, iusto omnis facilis est corrupti veniam vitae,
          a sunt exercitationem laudantium, nisi soluta! Commodi porro necessitatibus minima tenetur, ipsum quam fuga consequuntur recusandae nesciunt quidem!
        </p>
        <p></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It was strongly implied in the question that the markup can't be changed.

Comment: @isherwood I think you're assuming that.  @ Aminanessa hasn't clarified if different solutions can be used.

Comment: I do agree, he specified it but in the comments the OP should have updated its question. But if you're changing the structure, don't keep the useless table, it could be a way [simpler structure](https://codepen.io/cedricbeausseron/pen/OJZvagQ)

Answer (score 0):

Without touching the HTML, the CSS is the following:

```css
.td {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.p {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}


/*new code from here*/

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body>table>tbody>tr>td>p:nth-child(8),
  body>table>tbody>tr>td>p:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
  }
  body>table>tbody>tr>td>p:nth-child(3),
  body>table>tbody>tr>td>p:nth-child(7) {
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  body>table>tbody>tr>td>p:nth-child(3) {
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  body>table>tbody>tr>td>p:nth-child(2),
  body>table>tbody>tr>td>p:nth-child(6) {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3><strong>Title</strong></h3>
        <p>name</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>_____________________________________</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>Details</p>
        <p></p>
        <p>
          ___________________________________________________________________________
        </p>
        <p></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```